# When does the vaIue of the InvokeRequired property change?

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, invokerequired

When i want to use delegate class to make call while windows form working, i always have to use InvokeRequired. It is ok. But who changed the InvokeReuqired property while it is working.
Please check this image:
[image]

Comment: If you are not on the event thread then InvokeRequired will be true, as it needs to get on the proper thread before it can make changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `Delegate.BeginInvoke` in `button1_Click`, which means `SayListeyeEkle` will be called in a thread-pool thread - which means it's entirely correct for `InvokeRequired` to be true. It *wouldn't* be true if you called `ListeyeEkle` directly from `button1_Click`, in the UI thread.

Comment: +1 good catch on the use of delegate.BeginInvoke, maybe he intended to call this.BeginInvoke?

Answer (score 6):

[`InvokeRequired`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) is `true` when the control is accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on, and `false` otherwise. 
 To more directly answer your question, it's not that the `InvokeRequired` property "changes" at a specific point in time; it's more accurate to say that it may return different values based on the thread you access it from.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean "change the InvokeRequired property" ?  Do you mean that the true/false value is changing ?  If it returns true, and you make the delegate call to BeginInvoke, then after that, in the delegate, the value better **have** changed.  The whole point is to "switch" to the thread that the control was *created on*.  When a line of code with InvokeRequired is executed on any thread other than the thread the control was created on, InvokeRequired will return true. Only when executed on the same thread the control was created on will it return false.  The property could have been named 
`NotOnThreadIWasCreatedIn`, cause thats really all it's doing.  It's named `InvokeRequired` to coomunicate what it needs to be used for...